# why we can't delete the trust line with ripple?

Tags: ripple

We can add trust line in our ripple wallet, but there is no option to delete this. 
The only way we can do is just set the limit to 0.

why is this and what is the benefit from this design?

Comment: All a "delete" option would do is set the limit to zero anyway. And "delete" may imply to people that it does something to the balance. (Related, there has been talk of a "forgive", for positive or "pay back balance" for negative balances, option that would remove left over small, balances that are annoying to clear right now). Ripple is in beta, the JavaScript client especially so; so it just could be that the trust line interface isn't finished yet.